# Conda - package installing to the root environment instead of active environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have an environment set up on my windows machine using Conda. And when I try to install a package, it is not installing to the active environment, but instead, to the root environment. What's the deal.

```
(science) C:\Users\user>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
science                *  C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\science
root                      C:\Users\user\Anaconda3
```

I am active in my `science` environment, I try to install a package using pip.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/peplin/pygatt
```

But when I list the installed packages in the active environment:

```
(science) C:\Users\user>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\science:
#
```

There are none. If I deactivate my environment and try `conda list` again, it shows that it installed to the root environment. This is not the desired behavior.

```
(science) C:\Users\user>deactivate

C:\Users\user>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\user\Anaconda3:
#
_license                  1.1                      py36_1
alabaster                 0.7.9                    py36_0
anaconda                  4.3.1               np111py36_0
...
pygatt                    3.1.1                     <pip>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried creating a second environment. If I install pygatt to the second environment and then swap over to the first environment and try `pip list` then the pygatt is in the first environment as well. It's like these environments don't do what they are supposed to.

Comment: Can you try installing the same package using `conda` instead of `pip`?

Comment: You have to install pip into the environment where you want to do the install

Comment: what is the output of "where pip" ? And could it be that you have a cloned environment? (I think there was a bug some time ago)

Comment: The output of where pip is :
`C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe`
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe`

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I can't install the same package using conda, because as far as I know you can only install from source using pip and not conda.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you are using the root `pip`, this is why you don't see any of your installed packages inside your virtual environment.

To use the pip specific to a virtual environment:

- first install pip in the virtual env:
  `conda install -n science pip` (now the `science` environment will have its own `pip`).
- Then, locate that `pip` file wherever your conda environments are stored (for me it's `.../anaconda/envs/`).
- Now, you can install your packages using that local `pip` file something along the lines of: 
  `.../anaconda/envs/science/bin/pip install something`.

The thing is, unless you specify to conda that you want to install something specifically to a virtual env, it will end up in the root env (I'm not sure if this is by design, but this is what happenes on my machine). So if you want to install to a virtual env:

- `conda install -n env_name package_name` if it's a `conda` install.
- `.../anaconda/envs/science/bin/pip install something` if it's a `pip` install.

Comment: When we say source activate science ; 
by default, it should use pip from local environment...right ?