# pip in a (mini)conda environment installs packages in the global site-packages directory

Tags: python-3.x, pip, miniconda

As the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713502/where-to-install-pip-packages-inside-my-conda-environment) indicates, `pip` in a `conda-env` should install a package in the `site-packages` directory of env's `python`. In my case, however, `pip` (launched within the `env`) is trying to install in the *global* python `site-packages`.
Additionally, the installation in the `site-packages` of my *global* `python` is not so very clean either: newly installed packages fall under  `/Users/massimopinto/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/Users/massimopinto/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages` , that is the directory is nested within itself, so I need to manually move the new package to make it usable.

Would a re-configuration of `pip` work? Any advice would be much appreciated.

`pip` in use (21.2.4):

```
(spekpy) massimopinto@MacBook-Air-2 spekpy_release % which pip
/Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/bin/pip
```

(env's) `pip` configuration:

```
(spekpy) massimopinto@MacBook-Air-2 spekpy_release % pip config list
freeze.timeout='10'
global.editor='vim'
global.timeout='60'
```

home's pip configuration:

```
(spekpy) massimopinto@MacBook-Air-2 spekpy_release % cat ~/.pip/pip.conf
[global]
timeout = 60

[freeze]
timeout = 10
```

running on a MacOS Monterey 12.0.1, conda 4.10.3, Python 3.9.7.

##### Edited

As at a suggestion by @flyingteller, the output of

`/Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/bin/python -m pip install . >> spekpy-install.log`

is

```
Processing /Users/massimopinto/Progetti Git/spekpy_release
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from spekpy==2.0.6) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from spekpy==2.0.6) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->spekpy==2.0.6) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: spekpy
  Building wheel for spekpy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for spekpy (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for spekpy: filename=spekpy-2.0.6-py3-none-any.whl size=66391250 sha256=86962e10ec6182d7f0522dcf0d3e1d264b9d16d3659d5d5af038631d99bd8039
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/qs/hcv45zhn46q0p6xwndbc51fw0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-etx845ts/wheels/c3/93/d0/2db997ad51d9b10f0b0acac3a1f27240cca3d41a8cac3265ab
Successfully built spekpy
Installing collected packages: spekpy
Successfully installed spekpy-2.0.6
```

but the installation is still in
`/Users/massimopinto/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/Users/massimopinto/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/spekpy`

Comment: Can you also try `type pip`? It might be that you have configured an alias for pip. Save option is to use `python -m pip install`

Comment: `type pip` gives out: `pip is /Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/bin/pip`

Comment: That looks correct to me. I guess using `/Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/python -m pip install <some-package>` does not change anything? Can you post the complete output of a pip install done in this way that results in installation in the global site-packages?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have edited the post to include the output of the command that you suggested. Could this behavior be related to a pip config file that is located elsewhere?

Comment: Every location mentioned in the output only references `/Users/massimopinto/opt/miniconda3/envs/spekpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. It sounds really odd that the package installed in the end ends up in another location

Answer (score 1):

You might be using global pip, install pip in the environment and try.

```
conda create --no-default-packages -n myenv pip
```

This link might help [Conda - package installing to the root environment instead of active environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193194/conda-package-installing-to-the-root-environment-instead-of-active-environment?rq=4)

Comment: This is going in the right direction, thank you. ```$conda env list``` now *does* return the package that I have installed locally with pip. But I am still failing to import it in a code.